# My GPU is not recognized until I open the Preferences window

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu

I have a problem with Blender not recognizing my GPU on startup. Every time I start Blender and either start a new project or open an existing one, the render device is not recognized and it defaults to using the CPU.

[image: Render device greyed out when set to GPU Compute]

When opening the Preference window it will still remain unavailable until you switch to the "System" tab and then move the window.

[image: System Preferences before moving the window, Render device still greyed out.]
System Preferences before moving the window, Render device still greyed out.

[image: System Preferences after moving the window, Render device now available as GPU Compute.]
System Preferences after moving the window, Render device now available as GPU Compute.

Due to this weird bug I now always have to open my System Preferences before I begin. Even when I save the project with the right settings it will not work when I start up Blender the next time. This has been for months now over several Blender versions but I didn't feel like asking here until now.

I also made a video to show the bug:
[YouTube video showing the weird Blender behavior.](https://youtu.be/FaTPrjI0FZ4)

I am using the following hard- and software:

- Windows 10 Pro 20H2 (OS build: 19042.1348)
- Blender 2.93.6
- GeForce Game Ready Driver: 496.76

System:

- Intel i7-8700k
- Asus GeForce GTX 1080 Ti Turbo
- Corsair Vengeance LPX CMK32GX4M2B3000C15 (32 GB)(2x 16 GB)
- Samsung 960 EVO 500GB
- Samsung 850 EVO 1TB

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the issue. Of course this happens right after posting it...

Even though the settings in the Preference menu were already saved and the CUDA device was always selected when I opened up the menu, clicking "Save Preferences" again seemed to do the trick. I also had "Auto Save" turned on so I don't know why saving it again helped but apparently the "Auto Save" doesn't do anything.

[image: Save Preferences button in the preferences menu]

Click "Save Preferences" again if you encounter the problem.

I hope this also helps others that might encounter the issue.